# Visualize data on realtime via socket is too slow with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, sockets

I want to plot a data that received from a sever via socket. I will parse the data on client. For example, data is `0 1 2` indicates that 0 is index, 1 is data of sub figure 0 and 2 is data of sub figure 1. With the bellow code, I can visualize data using matplotlib on realtime, however, the visualization becomes very slow after 10 seconds, and it looks like that it works on main thread (mean I cannot open other task). Could you suggest to me any solution to speed up the visualization or do it in background thread?

```
import socket            
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a socket object
s = socket.socket()        
# Define the port on which you want to connect
port = 8080               
# connect to the server on local computer
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
fig.tight_layout()

subfig1_data = []
subfig2_data = []
x_data = []
while(1):
    # receive data from the server and decoding to get the string.
    message_received = s.recv(1024).decode()
    # 0 1 2
    data = message_received.split(" ")
    x_data.append(int(data[0]))
    subfig1_data.int(data[1])
    subfig2_data.int(data[2])
    
    axs[0, 0].plot(x_data, subfig1_data,'-o',alpha=0.8, color="blue")
    axs[0, 1].plot(x_data, subfig2_data,'-o',alpha=0.8, color="green")
    
    fig.show()
    plt.pause(0.00001)
# close the connection
s.close()
```

Comment: every time you get a message you pretty much recreate the entire plot, which isn't particularly fast. you will probably want to use something that can stream data to your plot, maybe `dash` but i'm no expert

Comment: It’s worse than that.  You keep adding more and more lines to your plot. Use one line and change its data before each draw using set_xdata and set_ydata.  Also suggest preallocating your array using numpy.  Appending to a list will get slow with lots of data